# Is it possible to pass schemalocation as relative path in wsdl?

Tags: import, xsd, wsdl, wsdlpull

I'm using WsdlPull library to parse the WSDL file.
Is it possible to provide relative path in the schemaLocation whiling importing external XSD inside WSDL?

e.g.

```
<types>
<xsd:schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsd:import namespace="http://myprovider/namespace1/namespace1" schemaLocation="schema1.xsd"/>
</schema>
</types>
```

Answer (score 0):

Schemas should be resolved relative to the containing document (in this case the WSDL's Url), so this should work. In fact we have WSDL files that do exactly what you appear to be trying to do.

However the implementation is given quite a lot of freedom during the resolution process (for example allowing it to transform the url causing it to load from a cache rather than the actual url).

As your positing this I assume this is not working?

Comment: yeah, this is not working with WsdlPull parser. What WSDL standard says? Any idea?